# c++ wrapping simple arithmetic types

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, operator-overloading

I would like to extend int32_t and int64_t with default constructors. I suppose I have to define new types using operator<> and operator2<> from boost opertators.hpp.

1. Would it be enough, are there any examples?
2. Does this approach has any impact from c++11/14. I do not see universal references used in operators.hpp. Does it make sense to simply type these classes to take advantage of c++11/14 features - it is tedious but relatively simple?

Comment: `int32_t` is not a class type, so it doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by adding "default constructors" to numeric types? Do you want variables to be initialized with `0` instead of remaining uninitialized?

Comment: How would integers benefit from forwarding (universal) references?

Comment: @dyp, yes I want it to be initialized with 0 and I do not like using initialization list - mostly to maintain closer resemblance to the original jave code being ported

Comment: I have become convinced that initializing *every* variable is **not** a good idea: There are several static analysers for C++ which can find code paths were a variable is used without having been initialized. This is a **better** approach in my opinion, since `0`, or any kind of default value, can be an incorrect initialization. Consider multiplication, where `1` not `0` is the neutral element.

Comment: @dyp I am porting java code that has all integral types initialized to zero. BTW, I do believe that not having default initialization  for primitive types is counter productive for mass use by under-qualified workforce.

Comment: I'll counter that with mass-deployment of static analysers ;) (really, I think regular and systematic use of a static analyser is a good idea). Not quite sure what to think about the Java porting aspect, though. Might be a practical solution.

Comment: Static analyzers means order, mass-deployment means anarchy - there are two different worlds with just a few intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the motivation, but the practice of never having an integral type uninitialised will probably result in less heartache in the end.

Nevertheless, this might be a good starting point. You'll notice that no operators are required for normal arithmetic.

```
#include <iostream>


template<class Type, Type original_value>
struct safe_integral
{
    safe_integral()
    : _v(original_value)
    {}

    safe_integral(Type t)
    : _v(t)
    {}


    operator const Type&() const { return _v; }
    operator Type&() { return _v; }
private:
    Type _v;
};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    using safe_int = safe_integral<int, 0>;

    safe_int x;
    cout << "original value: " << x << endl;

    x += 6;
    cout << "adding 6: " << x << endl;

    safe_int y = x;
    safe_int z = x + 6;
    safe_int w = x + z;

    cout << "w is : " << w << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
original value: 0
adding 6: 6
w is : 18
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. I suppose considering that 'Type' is a primitive I am wondering is there a penalty of returning const reference instead of value?

Comment: either way the optimiser will produce the same perfect code. returning references or copies in source code are just expressions of conceptual intent. The compiler will do the right thing regardless.

Comment: ... because there are no side-effects of optimising a read of an integral reference to a copy.